# How can I get the IP address of users opening my heroku app?

Tags: heroku, ip, client

Is there a way to view the IP addresses of people who have visited my web application which was deployed with heroku? swish-prophet.herokuapp.com

Answer (score 2):

From within your app's code, you can get the IP address of the person making the request using the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR` HTTP header.

You can also see that information in your app logs with the `heroku logs` command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] with php.
But you need to consider that some users are behind a proxy system, so there's no way to register that users correct address.
Some websites use REMOTE_ADDR such as:

[IP Chicken](https://ipchicken.com/)

[Mi IP](https://miip.es/)

[Meu IP](https://www.meuip.pt/)

[My IP Address](http://www.myipaddress.com)